# In the end of kaliyuga , Will people live only for 20 years and eat only non veg?

Tags: kali-yuga

In [this](http://www.harekrishnatemple.com/chapter19.html) article, it is mentioned that in the end of kaliyuga , people will live only 20 for years and eat only non-veg.

> By now already 5000 years of Kali yuga have passed and it is predicted that by the end of the yuga people will hardly be older than 20 years and their only food will be meat.

**Question** : why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum age of human beings will become fifty years as per [Srimad Bhagavatham 12.2.11](http://www.srimadbhagavatamclass.com/srimad-bhagavatam-canto-12-chapter-02-text-11/)

> trimsad vimsati varsani paramayuh kalau nrnam

**Meaning:**

*The maximum duration of life for human beings in Kali-yuga will become fifty years.*

About eating flesh, as per [Srimad Bhagavatam 12.2.09;](http://www.srimadbhagavatamclass.com/srimad-bhagavatam-canto-12-chapter-02-text-09/) people will eat both flesh and Veg-Foods.

> saka-mulamisa-ksaudra- phala-puspasti-bhojanah  anavrstya
>   vinanksyanti durbhiksa-kara-piditah

**Meaning:**

*Harassed by famine and excessive taxes, people will resort to eating leaves, roots, flesh, wild honey, fruits, flowers and seeds. Struck by drought, they will become completely ruined.*